# How to cache a React app with service workers

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Im just wondering how to handle this. I want to have my whole app cached.
Im have tried something like this which doesnt seem to work

```
self.addEventListener('install',(e)=>{
  console.log('installed');

})

self.addEventListener('activate',(e)=>{
  console.log('activated');
  self.skipWaiting();
})

self.addEventListener('fetch',(e)=>{
  e.respondWith(
    fetch(e.request)
      .then(res=>{
        const resClone = res.clone();
        caches.open(cacheName).then(cache=>{
          cache.put(e.request, resClone);
        })
        return res;

      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('no connection');
        caches.match(e.request).then(res => { return res })
      })
  )
})
```

Does anyone know how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me,

```js
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
      if (response) {
        return response;
      } else {
        return fetch(event.request)
          .then(function(res) {
            return caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
              cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
              return res;
            });
          })
         
      }
    })
  );
});
```

This tells the service worker to read from cache first and then network if there is no response from cache.
One thing to keep in mind, this will not check for any updates made to the files. If you change your react code, the service worker will load the previous files it has in cache.

To solve this you can use workbox's staleWhileRevalidate which updates the cache whenever there is network connection.

A less convenient solution would be to delete the cache on service worker activation:

```js
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys()
    .then(function(keyList) {
      return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
        return caches.delete(key);

      }));
    })
  );
  return self.clients.claim();
});
```

Whenever a new service worker is installed the cache is removed and a new one is created.

Comment: Interesting thank you i will look into this. Can you see why mine is not working?

Comment: @ST you're returning res outside of the then block of fetch(e.request). this makes the returned res undefined since res is not in the reach of return.

Comment: On the example you sent - What if there is always a cache? Hpw will your app ever update?

Comment: That's the issue with this approach. Even when you change the app the service worker will still load the old version it has in cache and so your changes won't appear in the browser. You can either delete the cache that contains the old files by hand, or set up the service worker to delete the cache once activated, but you need to change something in your service worker to force the browser to install the service worker again and run the activation code again and delete the old cache.

Comment: While in development, this method of caching is far from ideal. In a deployed production build however, since you won't be making changes as much, this strategy makes more sense. But you still need to change something in the service worker to make sure that end users will get the latest version for the reasons I previously mentioned.

Comment: Your best bet is Workbox. It was created by google and they have implemented various caching strategies in it for you to use such as staleWhileRevailidate which updates cache content whenever there is internet. you can also set an expiration date for the files in cache and workbox will delete them automatically once they pass their expiration date. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox

Comment: Awesome thank you sir i will use workbox for this

Answer (score 1):

Like one childish way would be to view the page source and check what js, css files are being used by react and cache them manually.

**This will not work in production, you will have to manually check the files in the build directory and update the service-worker**

Or a better and sensible way of doing it would be to use `workbox` (a npm package from google) which is going to handle all this clutter